# JavaScript - Detect HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML textarea element. I want to prevent a user from entering any HTML tags in this area. How do I detect if a user has entered any HTML a textarea with JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: You don't want to use Javascript for this. Just disabling Javascript in webbrowser already sets the XSS world wide open.

Comment: I urge you to return and read the other answers here, the solution you chose is terrible.

Comment: Warning to readers: Don't do this. Preventing users from entering or submitting HTML is **never** a sane solution to a security problem. You must either filter the data server side when receiving it or (much better) handle the problem when using the data (rendering, or prepare for rendering).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

firstly, bear in mind that you'll need to re-validate on the server side, since anyone can fake a http post, and if they have javascript disabled then of course you have no control :)

what i'd do is

```
<textarea onkeypress="disableHtml(this);" name="text"></textarea>
```

and for the javascript

```
function disableHtml(element) {
  element.value = element.value.replace(/[<>]/g, '');
}
```

another way to do this would be to replace < and > with &lt; and &gt; on the server side, which is the better way because it's secure and people can still frown >:)

[edit : you can make the regexp as clever as you like, if you want to only detect certain tags for instance]

Comment: This will still leave the body of the HTML element — element name and attributes, etc. in cases where someone pasted in some markup.

Comment: yep but it won't be valid html so it doesn't matter. server-side sanitisation is definitely the best policy anyway

Comment: This is a terrible method. As @robusto said but @odea ignored, simply pasting and submiting will get around this method.

Comment: there is no client-side method to avoid getting around it 100%. that's why i've continually advocated server-side stuff. @robusto said, if i understand, that if someone pastes in <a name="hi"> then it will still show a name="hi" without the < and >, that's all. or did i misunderstand you, robusto?

Comment: Server side validation is the best practice possible...  If you're practicing client-side validation, why can't I just write a webpage to send you my username as `' DELETE * FROM * '`? [or in your case, </div></span></a></div></span></a></body></html><script> window.location="viruses.com"; </script>

Comment: This is definitely unsafe against XSS.

Comment: what's with all the downvotes? the solution does what OP wanted - to prevent people from entering any HTML tags in the textarea. i've also strongly suggested that they investigate a server-side solution as a safer method.

Comment: I have to -1 this, it's a horrendous solution.  Aside from the reasons mentioned here (that this will only replace the `<` and `>` sign), imagine if someone enters `3 is > 1 but < 5`.  The result is `3 is 1 but 5`

Comment: @oedo: downvotes are used for a number of reasons and shouldn't really be taken personally.  The solution you provided is flawed in many ways and should not be implemented at all.

Answer (score 6):

One of the ways is to let the `keypress` event return `false` when the pressed key matches `<` or `>`. To distinguish real HTML tags from innocent "lesser than" and "greater than" signs, you may need to put some regex in. And since you can't parse HTML reliably with regex... There's however a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) way:

```
var sanitized = $('<div>').html(textareavalue).text();
```

The normal practice is however to just let the client enter whatever it want and sanitize HTML during *display* by the server side view technology in question. How to do it depends on the view technology you're using. In for example PHP you can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for this and in JSP/JSTL the [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html). This is more robust since Javascript can be disabled/hacked/spoofed by the client.

Comment: you also sanitize (in a different way) before saving to a database.

Comment: +1 for `htmlspecialchars` (and its analogues in other languages). HTML-escaping on output is absolutely the correct way to deal with `<` and `&` characters in user-input text. Trying to block or filter is not.

Answer (score 3):

Initial considerations:

- XML != HTML, so I will consider that html are not allowed, but XML it is.
- All html tags should be deleted, not just escaped (escape html is much easier).
- We don't want that the user lose the position of his pointer while he is writting (that is very anoying).

First of all, define a function to replace html tags by '':

```
/**
* This function delete html tags from a text, even if the html tag is 
* not well formed.
* This function update the pointer position to maintain it after the replacement.
* @param {string} text The text to modify
* @param {int} initPos The current position of the pointer in the text 
* @return {int} The new pointer position
*/
function removeHtmlTags( text, initPos )
{
    // Define the regex to delete html tags
    if (undefined===removeHtmlTags.htmlTagRegexp)
    {
        removeHtmlTags.htmlTagRegexp = new RegExp('</?(?:article|aside|bdi|command|'+
            'details|dialog|summary|figure|figcaption|footer|header|hgroup|mark|'+
            'meter|nav|progress|ruby|rt|rp|section|time|wbr|audio|'+
            'video|source|embed|track|canvas|datalist|keygen|output|'+
            '!--|!DOCTYPE|a|abbr|address|area|b|base|bdo|blockquote|body|'+
            'br|button|canvas|caption|cite|code|col|colgroup|dd|del|dfn|div|'+
            'dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|footer|form|h1|h2|h3|h4|'+
            'h5|h6|head|hr|html|i|iframe|img|input|ins|kdb|keygen|label|legend|'+
            'li|link|map|menu|meta|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|option|p|param|'+
            'pre|q|s|samp|script|select|small|source|span|strong|style|sub|'+
            'sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|title|tr|u|ul|var|'+
            'acronym|applet|basefont|big|center|dir|font|frame|'+
            'frameset|noframes|strike|tt)(?:(?: [^<>]*)>|>?)', 'i');
    }

    // Delete html tags
    var thereIsMore=true;
    removeHtmlTags.htmlTagRegexp.lastIndex=0;
    // While I am not sure that all html tags are removed.
    while (thereIsMore)
    {
        var str = text.match(removeHtmlTags.htmlTagRegexp);
        if ( str!=null) // There is a match
        {
            text = text.replace(str[0], '');
            // Update the position
            if (str.index < initPos) 
                initPos= Math.max(initPos-str[0].length,str.index);
        }
        else thereIsMore = false;
    }

    // If getCaretPosition fail, the initPos may be negative
    if (initPos<0) initPos=0;

    return {text: text, pos: initPos};
}
```

Notes:
I decided following replacements e.g.:

```
'<div>' -> ''
'<div selected' -> ' selected'
'<div selected>' -> ''
'<div    >' -> ''
```

Second, we need a function to get/set the carret position, because on updating the textarea content, it will reset. Further more, the position may change if any tag is deleted before the carret position.

```
/**
 * This function get/set the position of the carret in a node.
 * If the value is set, this function try to set the new position value.
 * Anyway, it return the (new) position.
 * @param {Element} node The textarea element
 * @param {int} value The new carret position
 * @return {int} The (new) carret position 
 */
function caretPosition(node, value) 
{
    // Set default Caret pos, will be returned if this function fail.
    var caretPos = 0;

    // Ensure that value is valid
    value = parseInt(value);

    // Set the new caret position if necesary
    if (!isNaN(value)) // We want to set the position
    {
        if (node.selectionStart)
        {
            node.selectionStart=value;
            node.selectionEnd= value;
        }
        else if(node.setSelectionRang)
        {
            node.focus();
            node.setSelectionRange(value, value);
        }
        else if (node.createTextRange)
        {
            var range = node.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', value);
            range.moveStart('character', value);
            range.select();
        }
    }

    // Get the position to return it.
    if (node.selectionStart) return node.selectionStart;
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        node.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.moveStart('character', -node.value.length);
        caretPos = sel.text.length;
    }

    return caretPos;
}
```

Third, create a main function to remove html tags from the textarea and set the carret position.

```
/**
 * This event function remove html tags from the textarea with id=text 
 */
function updateText()
{
    // Get the textarea
    var t = document.getElementById('text');

    // Get the caret position
    var pos = caretPosition(t);

    // Remove html from the text
    var result = removeHtmlTags(t.value, pos);
    t.value = result.text;

    // Set the new caret position
    caretPosition(t, result.pos);
}
```

Finally, add event listeners to update the textarea on modification:

- Key press
- Past
- Drop

We should be able to use "oninput" for all 3 events, but (ofc) IE fail.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           <!-- Copy all the js code here. -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" oninput="updateText();" 
            ondrop="setTimeout('updateText();',0);" 
            onpaste="setTimeout('updateText();',0);" 
            onkeyup="updateText();" id='text'></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope it help you :-)
Escain

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression, like

```
if ( textArea.value.match(/<\/*[a-z][^>]+?>/gi) ) {
  // do something about it
}
```

where "textArea" is the ID of your `textarea` element.

Answer (score 1):

What can you consider as HTML tags? Is `<b>` a tag? What about the middle characters in `I <3 how 5 is > 4`?

I think you should not limit users with your strictness. Don't be a Steve Jobs.